# getting mysql dates 3 days earlier when all dates in timestamp format

Tags: mysql

I have all dates stored as timestamps (int) in the database.

how can I get dates that are exactly 3 days earlier?

I tried

```
SELECT date from user WHERE  DATE_ADD(DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( `created` ) ), INTERVAL 3 DAY) = CURDATE()
```

is that the best/most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date
FROM user
WHERE created = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Note: no function used on the `created` column in where clause. This query should be able to use index.

Answer (score 1):

i think the database prefer to only do the date add 2 times to define the range, like:

```
SELECT date FROM user
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)) <= `created`
AND `created` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY));
```

Test putting DESCRIBE keyword before SELECT in both case, and the database respond with how its going to perform the query